# Perl Regex to find all strings formed using substring

Tags: perl

Using Perl RegEx, How to find largest superstring in a sentence, when superstring is a repeatation of 1 or more substring.

For Ex:

```
$sentence = "zsabcxyzabcabcabccde_xdrabcabcrte__23abcerabcabccbabacxyz";

$subStr = "abc";
```

I want to find all the occurrences of abc and largest one in that.

Output:

```
abc

abcabcabc

abcabc

abc

abcabc
```

Largest string is abcabcabc

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html

Answer (score 2):

Try as below one

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $sentence = "zsabcxyzabcabcabccde_xdrabcabcrte__23abcerabcabccbabacxyz";

my ($larg) = sort{length($b)<=>length($a)} $sentence =~ m/((?:abc)+)/g;

print $larg,"\n";
```

---

If don't want to store it means, make a loop

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $sentence = "zsabcxyzabcabcabccde_xdrabcabcrte__23abcerabcabccbabacxyzabcabcabcabc";
my $longstr;
my $len = 0;
while($sentence=~m/((?:abc)+)/g)
{
    $longstr = $1 and $len = length($1) if(length($1) > $len)
}
```

the above one is in single regex with `(?{})` but **not recommended**

```
my $sentence = "zsabcxyzabcabcabccde_xdrabcabcrte__23abcerabcabccbabacxyzabcabcabcabc";
my $lar = 0;
my $larg;
$sentence=~m/((?:abc)+)(?{ $larg = $1 and $lar=(length $1) if(length $1 > $lar )}) \G/x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Compile a regex using a quantifier. `+` says 'one or more'.

So your "substr" becomes `((?:abc)+)` the outer brackets to 'capture', the inner brackets non capturing. Otherwise you'll also get the 'partial' hits in the array - although the net result isn't changed much, because the longest hit will still sort to the top.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $sentence = "zsabcxyzabcabcabccde_xdrabcabcrte__23abcerabcabccbabacxyz";
my $substring = "abc";
my $regex = qr/((?:$substring)+)/;
my @matches = $sentence =~ m/$regex/g;

print Dumper \@matches;

#Then sort it:

my ( $longest ) = sort { length ( $b ) <=> length ( $a ) } @matches;

print $longest,"\n";
```

Comment: Might be necessary to escape meta characters in  `$substring` (quotemeta)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mkHun and @Sobrique... 
I have used **@matches = $str =~ m/(abc)+/ng;** and then sorting. 
/n makes it looks much simpler which is available from 5.22, i think.

Comment: Don't write a comment as an answer. You can put this as a comment below your question or edit it into your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: this is not just a comment. Can be considered as a different answer.

Comment: Ok, I missed the `/n` flag. Great that you found it, but still it could be posted as a comment I think

Answer (score 0):

The best way is next: `((?:abc)+)` with sorting after finding matches